# Program won't run after adding simple cout

Tags: c++, gcc

Trying to get (back) into C++ and going through an exercise in a book I get a strange error.

Using code::blocks + GCC

This is the current program.

```
    #include "std_lib_facilities.h";
    int main()
    {

    double val, smallest = 9999, largest = 0;
    string strunit;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cout << "Enter value: ";
            cin >> val >> strunit;

            if (strunit == "in") {
                    val = val*0.254;
            } else if (strunit == "cm") {
                val = val/100;
            }
            if ( val > largest) {
                largest = val;
            } else if (val < smallest) {
                smallest = val;
            }
            cout << "Largest: " << largest << "smallest: " << smallest << endl;

        }

   return 0;
}
```

I intended to use a while loop but right now it's a for. The result is the same however.

This is the Build result:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in drill_4 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\drill_4.exe obj\Debug\exe\principles_and_practices\drill_4\main.o   
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

The IDE claims the program has not been built and asks me to rebuild.

If I comment out pretty much any line the program will run.

I used one line if statements at first, with the same result.

I'm quite new to the IDE as well, so not sure where to find all the information I need, but I guess the pgrogram doesn't link properly?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try running gcc from the command line, without going through CodeBlocks?

Comment: Is this the full code.. I don't know what "std_lib_facilities.h" doing here but when i run this code with including <string> thats runs without a problem..

Answer (score 2):

Try using `#include<iostream>` and `using namespace std;`

Comment: If its the header from Stroustrup's drills, its all already in there via [`std_lib_facilities.h`](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h), including that hideous header-homed  `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Yea but his header doesn't seem to be working. He may be missing some files. Just so that he can get his code to run I would suggest #include<iostream>, #include<string> , and using namespace std; Once these were added, the code worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me when I typed this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

double val, smallest = 9999, largest = 0;
string strunit;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Enter value: ";
        cin >> val >> strunit;

        if (strunit == "in") {
                val = val*0.254;
        } else if (strunit == "cm") {
            val = val/100;
        }
        if ( val > largest) {
            largest = val;
        } else if (val < smallest) {
            smallest = val;
        }
        cout << "Largest: " << largest << "smallest: " << smallest << endl;

    }
    system("pause");
}
```

It doesn't like that header your including for some reason.. You may have to download some extra file with VS to use it? Are you using Visual Studios?

Comment: Tried to compile from command line with the same result. I'll use separate include for now.

Answer (score 1):

cout is behind the namespace std in the iostream header file.

The compiler is not aware of the object instance of cout or cin for that matter.

You could alternatively add the header and use std::cout.

```
#include <iostream>

.....
std::cout << "hellow world";
```